# Why am I still getting a warning after including app_engine_apis in app.yaml?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have just deployed an app on Google App Engine using `gcloud app deploy` and I get a warning such as below:

```
WARNING: There is a dependency on App Engine APIs, but they are not enabled in your app.yaml. Set the app_engine_apis property.
```

So what I did was to include `app_engine_apis: true` in the `app.yaml`, saved it, and proceed to `gcloud app deploy` again. However I'm still getting the same warning. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the warning by running:

```
google beta app deploy
```

instead of

```
google app deploy
```

I got the fix from [this document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/530a54b0fc0eb74d9dc29b19b7c4cdfab0556ebc/README.md). I believe it's necessary because at the time of this answer the migration of the python2 app_engine_apis to python3 isn't complete.